In Firebase Analytics Dashboard showing Landing Page as not set
Hello Team,
I am using @react-native-firebase/analytics for capturing analytics in react native android and iOS apps , But on the analytics dashboard I can not  see Landing Page analytics.  I can see (not set) value for the same. I can see Events and pages and screen
Can someone help what exact code is required for capturing landing Page analytics.
refer screenshot what I see in firebase console

Landing page dimension is for web measurement. There is nothing like "Landing page" in mobile app measurement.
If you are capturing screens in your react native app, go to section Engagement -> Pages and screens -> break it down by screen class or screen name.
